# Aligning a textblock

Tags: textpos

For a titlepage, I want to add a text at a specific place. Now, the textpos package provides such an option, but when I specfiy something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.75cm, right=1.75cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{textblock*}{7cm}(1.75cm, \dimexpr\textheight-15cm\relax)
        Your specific text goes here. It will be 15cm above the bottom of the page and have a left margin of 1.75cm. The width is 7cm.
    \end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

then the *top* of the box is 15cm above the bottom of the page. However, I want the bottom of the textblock to always be 15cm above the bottom of the page, so that when I add text to the block, the last line always stays in the same place. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `textpos` documentation says at page 6

> You may give an optional argument to the `{textblock}` environment, specifying which point in the box is to be placed at the specified point:

> ```
> \begin{textblock}{⟨hsize⟩}[⟨ho⟩,⟨vo⟩](⟨hpos⟩,⟨vpos⟩)
> text...
> \end{textblock}
> ```

> The coordinates `⟨ho⟩` and `⟨vo⟩` are fractions of the width and height of the text box, respectively, and state that the box is to be placed so that the reference point `(⟨ho⟩,⟨vo⟩)` within the box is to be placed at the point `(⟨hpos⟩,⟨vpos⟩)` on the page. The default specification is `[0,0]`, indicating the top left of the box; the argument `[0,1]` (for example) would specify the bottom left, and `[0.5,0.5]` the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}[0,1](1.75cm, \dimexpr\textheight-15cm\relax)
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}[0,1](8cm, \dimexpr\textheight-15cm\relax)
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text.
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]